# Regex in Python and save in csv

Tags: python, regex, csv

Input text file view:

```
64120655007 6173 0578 111 8th Avenue, 7th Floor 30319.
```

File consist a lot of lines

I only need the numbers from the line that do not have letters attached. How do I use regex to find only the numbers **without** letters attached and save the results in a new CSV?

Example results:

```
64120655007 6173 0578 111 30319.
```

Only need the numbers as indicated. If they have attached text, discard.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('the_file_name') as file:
    only_numbers = [re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', line) for line in file]
```

then save it to another file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the csv library?

```
import csv
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the string split method to split your line into 'words'.  Then you can use the isdigit string method to see if all the character in that 'word' are numbers.

Why the requirement to you regex.  Often times I see questioners pick regex first as a solution to their problem before they consider what the language offers